# Horizontal Asymptotes

Tags: limits, graphing-functions

> Find all asymptotes of: $$f(x) = \frac{a + be^x}{ae^x+b}$$

The way I've been taught is that the $+a$ and $+b$ in the numerator and denominator respectively do not contribute when x tends to infinity, therefore are negligible. Left with $f(x) = \frac{be^x}{ae^x} = \frac{b}{a}$, $y = \frac{b}{a}$
 is the only asymptote I was able to identify (through this method).

However, plotting the function with $a = 3$ and $b = 2$, there is clearly another horizontal asymptote, where $y = \frac{a}{b}$:

[image]

> Is there any way I could've known about the second asymptote without graphing?

Comment: Yes, look at what happens when $x \to -\infty$.

Comment: Don't the $e^{x}$ in the numerator and denominator cancel out, cancelling the $e^{-\infty}$ out?

Comment: No. $e^{-x}$ (and consequently $ae^{-x}$ and $be^{-x}$) become very small, so they are negligible. So in this case, the limit as $x \to -\infty$ is $\frac{a}{b}$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not understand; the $e^{-x}$ cancels out, leaving $y = f(x) = \frac{b}{a}$, doesn't it?

Comment: How does the $e^{-x}$ cancel out exactly? 

$$\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to -\infty}}ae^{-x}=0=\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to -\infty}}be^{-x}$$

so as you take the limit as $x\to {-\infty}$ you may as well consider these terms zero.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{1}{f(-x)}$.
So if $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to+\infty} f(x)=L\not=0$ then $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to-\infty} f(x)=\frac{1}{L}$.

Comment: Good catch ! (+1)

Answer (score 0):

The line $y = L$ is a horizontal asymptote of a function $f$ if 
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = L$$
or
$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = L$$
While rational functions have at most one horizontal asymptote, a function may have two different horizontal asymptotes.

Note that 
$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} e^x = 0$$
Hence, 
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{a + be^x}{ae^x + b} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{a + be^x}{ae^x + b} \cdot \frac{e^{-x}}{e^{-x}} = \lim_{x \to \infty} = \frac{ae^{-x} + b}{a + be^{-x}} = \lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{ae^x + b}{a + be^x} = \frac{b}{a}$$
provided that $a \neq 0$, and 
$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{a + be^x}{ae^x + b} = \frac{a}{b}$$
provided that $b \neq 0$.